# Yii2: How to use integer only in rules

Tags: validation, yii, frameworks, integer, yii2

I was wondering if there still is a integer only validator in Yii2. This is the old one from Yii but sadly this doesnt work.

```
'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is..!

```
[['type', 'media'], 'integer'],
```

where `type` and `media` are your attributes.For more details,use [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html) link.

Answer (score 1):

Yii2 does not defined numerical.
with Yii2
You can validate Float type validation by defining rule in model Like...

```
....other rules....
 [['area'],'integer', 'integerOnly' => false,],
 ...other rule...
```